# Feign client adding headers to file bytes

Tags: kotlin, file-upload, spring-cloud-feign

having a strange issue. I am trying to upload a binary file using feign client

```
 fun uploadChunk(
        @RequestHeader headerMap: Map<String, String>,
        @RequestPart fileChunk: MultipartFile
    ): ResponseObject
```

Here header map has  "Content-Type" to  "application/octet-stream"  and multipart file has the bytes. When request is sent it looks like

[image]

Here these headers Content-disposition , name , file-name which are added automatically should be removed from chunk when recived at api, but its not. any thoughts whats wrong here?